# How to populate Info.plist values dynamically in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

Can't figure out how to populate CFBundleVersion dynamically with ${BUNDLE_VERSION} which I would like to define as

```
BUNDLE_VERSION=`date "+%y%m%d"`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing command-line builds with xcodebuild, you can do something like

```
xcodebuild -target MyApp -configuration AppStore BUNDLE_VERSION=`date "+%y%m%d"`
```

However, I advise against doing this. An App Store app has three versions:

- The iTunes Connect version number (this is the only one normally shown to the user)
- CFBundleVersion
- CFBundleShortVersionString

I think they're all supposed to be of the form `[0-9]+.[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?`. To avoid confusion, I set them all to the same thing for App Store builds (we include CFBundleVersion/CFBundleShortVersionString in bug reports, and it's nice if they match CFBundleVersion). Non-App Store builds can include more info, since they don't need to be submitted.

I don't know if iTunes Connect lets you submit an app with CFBundleVersion that doesn't contain a ".", but I haven't extensively tested this.

Comment: CFBundleShortVersionString is what being used by AppStore.app and ITunes Store. CFBundleVersion is seen only from iTunesConnect's MetaData. I had CFBundleVersion as unsigned integers since 2008 with no problems. I am trying to make this field slightly usefull to identify time of the build, rather than application's version.

Comment: No; the store shows whatever enter as the "Version" in iTunes Connect. If you're going to use it as a timestamp, I'd be tempted to include the time too (yyyyMMdd.HHmmss); this means it's easier to differentiate between multiple builds from the same day. That said, a better way to tag the build is to include you own Info.plist key ("DetailVersion" perhaps) which can be in any format you like. I include the branch, SVN revision, configuration, and build number.

Comment: if you use Enterprise deployment model(or Ad-hoc), there is no Itunes Connect involved. In desktop iTunes software it shows CFBundleShortVersionString as version.

Comment: I specifically said App Store. Ad Hoc apps aren't shown on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need an Xcode configuration file and a configuration variable that you set at build time. This is [described in some detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20160516151012/http://blog.massanti.com/2009/09/20/automatic-build-numbering-increase-with-xcode/) at Diego Massanti’s blog. You’ll need to modify the build phase he describes to set the variable to the current date instead of incrementing the existing value.

Comment: I studied the lifecycle of xcode build. it evals Info.plist first and onlythen it execs build phases. It's not really dynamic as it creates a state to be used in the next iteration of the build. I have an improvement for Diego. He should really edit(postprocess) Info.plist in the built folder and gain the dynamic aspect. 
Thanks to you, I see how it can be achieved, but it's awfully ugly